# Sometimes (but not always) This custom info button doesn't display itself in full. Any ideas why?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qpushbutton, qtooltip

I have these 2 classes, one makes a custom button with an icon, some formatting and all that, and the other makes a custom tooltop that displays whenever the user hovers over the button, and it moves with the mouse.

Now sometimes, the tooltip gets cut off and doesnt display properly when i first hover over the info button, but when i then move my mouse somewhere else and re-enter the button, it displays fully.

[image: Not fully displayed]

Here is the code:

```
class InfoButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, string, size: int, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.string = string
        self.size = size
        self.parent_object = parent

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;"
                           "border: 0px solid;"
                           f"border-radius: {self.size}px;"
                           "color: #ffffff;")

        self.setIcon(QIcon('images\\icons\\black\\info48x48.svg'))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(self.size, self.size))

        self.custom_tooltip = CustomTooltip(self.string, self.parent_object)
        self.setToolTipDuration(0)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.custom_tooltip.showAtMouse()

    def leaveEvent(self, a0):
        self.custom_tooltip.hide()
```

```
class CustomTooltip(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.text = text
        self.label.setText(self.text)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.ToolTip | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: #aaaaaa; border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 12px; color: black; padding: 5px;")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def showAtMouse(self):
        cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        self.move(cursor_pos.x() - self.width() - 5, cursor_pos.y() - self.height() - 5)
        self.show()
```

I tried running it through chat gpt, but it spits out utter garbage with syntax that doesn't even work.
I have a GUI app with this info button implemented, and there are so far 2 cases where it gets used.
On the first case, it always works, and  on the second case it always fails the first time, and there is no difference in the usage of the info button, so it doesn't really make sense.

After meddling with the parents of the various objects, it seems that it affects it. But i still can't get it to display correctly.

I hope some of you beautiful people can help me with this :)

Comment: Well, i added:

f"min-height: {line_count*22};"
f"min-width: {max_char_count*8};"

to the style sheet of the CustomTooltip class, and that solved it.
Basically, i calculate the amount of lines, and the longest line, multiply it by some numbers that look about right, and then set the min size of the whole tooltip.
Though it is very clunky, it gets the job done.
I would love some actual solutions though :)

Comment: Your `CustomTooltip` embeds a child widget (the label), but you're not using any [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), so the parent will never know about the size requirements of its child. In any case, don't use arbitrary sizes unless you *really* know how to deal with them and widget size management. Besides, it shouldn't be necessary to have a container for just *one* widget, you should be able to directly subclass QLabel and avoid the problem completely (there may be some issues with the border and background, but I'm not sure, as it also depends on the OS).

Comment: As a slightly unrelated note, be aware that showing a tooltip that keeps itself **always** visible within the widget area is not only discouraged, but also annoying to many users. Tooltips should only be shown when required, possibly for a limited time. They are *tips*: how would you feel if somebody was *constantly* giving you the *same* suggestion all over again? Also, since you're not setting a *real* `toolTip` property, calling `setToolTipDuration()` is pointless. The correct implementation should either use an `event()` override (checking for QHelpEvents) or, at least, use a QTimer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went with the layout idea, because it could be that i need to add multiple widgets into the tooltip. As for the fact that it always stays visible, yes. That has been fixed too :) The tooltip now displays centered on the cursor (so that the user can possibly click on a link within the tooltip) and disappears after the cursor moves outside of it.

Comment: Good. Note that the point is not really about *where* the tooltip is shown, but how, when, for how long and its reactions to user events. Always remember what the common user expects, considering (but also despite) your personal habits. Nobody will force you to do something opposite to established conventions, but, as a developer, you have to consider them, no matter if you're writing a niche program that will be used by a few hundred users or the latest annoyingly update to an OS that will break most of their installed programs and habits (any reference to Apple is completely "casual" ;-) ).